# Excel XML: Formatting inline text

Tags: xml, excel

I am trying to apply inline styling to a cell within an Excel spreadsheet with the aim of having bold, non-bold and different coloured text within a single cell.

I am using the following:

```
<Row>
  <Cell ss:StyleID="s1">
    <ss:Data ss:Type="String" xml:space="preserve" xlmns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><Font>Black text</Font><B>Bold text</B><Font html:Color="#FF0000">Red text</Font></ss:Data>
  </Cell>
</Row>
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to have any effect. When I open in Excel, my text appears all black and non-bold.

I am completely stumped as I believe `<Font html:Color="#FF0000">Red text</Font>` and `<B>Bold text</B>` to be the correct elements to use.

Here is my full XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
   <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
      <Author>John</Author>
      <LastAuthor>Smith</LastAuthor>
      <LastPrinted>2013-11-13T12:16:09Z</LastPrinted>
      <Created>2011-10-05T11:29:15Z</Created>
      <LastSaved>2014-02-03T15:36:18Z</LastSaved>
      <Company>Microsoft</Company>
      <Version>14.00</Version>
   </DocumentProperties>
   <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
      <AllowPNG/>
   </OfficeDocumentSettings>
   <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
      <WindowHeight>9096</WindowHeight>
      <WindowWidth>22980</WindowWidth>
      <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
      <WindowTopY>252</WindowTopY>
      <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
      <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
   </ExcelWorkbook>

   <Styles>
      <Style xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:ID="s1">
         <Alignment ss:Vertical="Top" ss:WrapText="1"/>
         <Borders>
            <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
            <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
            <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
            <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
         </Borders>
         <Font xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11"/>
      </Style>
   </Styles>

   <Worksheet xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:Name="PDA Printout">
      <Table xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
         <Column ss:Width="500"/>
         <Row>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="s1">
               <ss:Data ss:Type="String" xml:space="preserve" xlmns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><Font>Black text</Font><B>Bold text</B><Font Color="#FF0000">Red text</Font></ss:Data>
            </Cell>
         </Row>
      </Table>
   </Worksheet>

</Workbook>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is seems it is possible. You just made a typo. :)

Change xlmns to xmlns

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I can confirm that Excel **does** support multiple styles within a single cell.

This can be proved by creating a new Excel file, applying several styles within a single cell and then saving as XML Spreadsheet 2003.

Comment: @CraigJohnstone hey you're right. I'll remove this wrong answer and try to see why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @CraigJohnstone Changed the answer. Please try it. I just saved a file with different formatting and copied the differences. :)

Comment: @CraigJohnstone Ah, you just made a typo. But I think it's good to keep this question as there where a lot of people saying it isn't possible when I searched for it.

Comment: Hours of banging my head on the desk over a typo!

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: WrapText="1" applies equally to columns doesn't?